# Create array of 0 and 1s that changes the position of the 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create an array in Excel that contains zeros and ones and shifts the 1 for each row I copy the array down.

Example:

```
Row 1: 1, 0, 0, 0
Row 2: 0, 1, 0, 0
Row 3: 0, 0, 1, 0
Row 4: 0, 0, 0, 1
```

I can't seem to think of any formula that would create such an array. Do you have an idea that could point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You just need `MUNIT()` function.

```
=MUNIT(4)
```

[image]

Another alternate is `MAKEARRAY()`.

```
=MAKEARRAY(4,4,LAMBDA(r,c,--(r=c)))
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you very much for your quick response!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this in Excel using a combination of functions like SEQUENCE, MOD, and TRANSPOSE. Here's an example formula that you can use:

Assuming you want to start with the array in cells A1:D1, and you want to generate the pattern in rows 2 to 5, you can use the following formulas:

In cell A2 (and then drag across to D2), enter the following formula:

```
=MOD(SEQUENCE(1,4,0,1),ROW(A2))
```

This formula uses the SEQUENCE function to generate a sequence of numbers from 0 to 3 (the size of your array), and then uses the MOD function to create the pattern you described. The ROW(A2) part ensures that the sequence resets when you copy the formula to the next row.

After entering the formula in A2, drag it across to D2 to fill the rest of the array.

Here's a breakdown of the formula:

**SEQUENCE(1,4,0,1):** Generates a sequence of numbers from 0 to 3.
**MOD(...,ROW(A2)):** Performs a modulo operation to create the shifting pattern. The ROW(A2) ensures that the modulo is based on the row number.
Now, when you copy the formula down to cells A3:A5, you will get the desired pattern:

```
Row 2: 0, 1, 0, 0
Row 3: 0, 0, 1, 0
Row 4: 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Adjust the range and formula as needed based on your specific requirements.

Comment: It will not create the pattern you described, but a fun fact is that we can have a sequence counter up to `n` starting at `1` and increasing the sequence pattern by 1 each row:
`=LET(n,10,MOD(SEQUENCE(1,n,0,1),SEQUENCE(n))+1)`